# Affordable and of good quality text to speech software

Tags: windows, linux, android, web-apps, speech-synthesis

I'm looking for paid options, because free isn't gonna be good. But many of paid options often vague on price or very expensive. Could you recommend some not expensive (something within about 50 dollars) software that doesn't sound like robot much.
And no restrictions on commercial use of audio.
It may be for Windows, Linux, Android or web.

Answer (score 2):

[image: intelligent speaker amazon polly text to speech browser extension podcast]

I am the developer of [Intelligent Speaker](https://intelligent-speaker.com/) - text to speech browser extension. We use the best available engine - [Polly from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/) - better than [Google's WaveNet](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/). No restrictions on commercial use of audio. Also, this product automatically syncs your added texts with your private podcast feed. $7 per month. But on the current free plan you can listen up to 1 hour per month.